# javascript executing block after getting data from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to let this block of code execute after uploading data to firebase, but I get "execute after uploading data completed" before "Annotaion added" in console... Am I using async wrong here?

```
uploadData()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("execute after uploading data completed")
        //THIS BLOCK
      })
```

```
async function uploadData() {
  
  .....

  //1. add to annotations
  //2. increment count in files
  //3. add to user's annotations
  db.collection("annotations")
    .doc(fileName)
    .set(updateField, { merge: true })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Annotation added!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise from `uploadData` that resolves when you want the `then` block to be executed.

Simplest is to just return the promise that `set()` returns, and not consume it:

```
async function uploadData() {
  
  .....

  //1. add to annotations
  //2. increment count in files
  //3. add to user's annotations
  return db.collection("annotations")
    .doc(fileName)
    .set(updateField, { merge: true });
}
```

If you really want to consume it, that'll work too:

```
  return db.collection("annotations")
    .doc(fileName)
    .set(updateField, { merge: true })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Annotation added!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callbacks or JavaScript `Promise` here.

For this case, using callbacks is the best.

Modifying your snippet:

```
function uploadData(callback) {
  
  .....

  //1. add to annotations
  //2. increment count in files
  //3. add to user's annotations
  db.collection("annotations")
    .doc(fileName)
    .set(updateField, { merge: true })
    .then(() => {
        callback(false, "Annotation Added!"); 
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        callback(true, error);
    });
}
```

```
uploadData((err, message) => {
    console.log("execute after uploading data completed")
    //THIS BLOCK

    //YOU CAN CHECK IF THERE IS A ERROR BY:
    if(err) {//Do something} 
    else {//Do something}
});
```

The parameters are callback(error, message). You can use anything. callback is just a function. You can also name the function `callback()` as `hello()`, `bye()`, etc. Anything you want. We are basically passing a function as a parameter which we call on updating the annotations so that, it is called after updating and not before it as you mentioned.